# Embedding all fonts with ghostscript makes pdf smaller

Tags: pdf, fonts, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I use ghostscript to embed missing fonts to my pdfs:

```
gswin64 -sFONTPATH=path_to_fonts -o path_topdf_2 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDEFSETTINGS=/default -dEmbedAllFonts=true path_to_pdf
```

I use -dPDEFSETTINGS=/default to have the same quality as before
Since I embed the missing fonts I expect the new files to have at least the same file size but the converted files are in many cases smaller as before. Can you explain this behavior?

Example file sizes:

old -> new

- 604 KB -> 407 KB
- 268 KB -> 173 KB
- 73 KB -> 80KB

Answer (score 1):

I am, by no means, an expert on GhostScript but I do know a few things about PDFs, I used to develop interactive PDFs with a combination of Adobe InDesign and Acrobat.

My understanding is that when you embed fonts, at least with Acrobat at that time, you're embedding a subset of the font set, any character that is not used in your PDF, is not embedded.

When I used to do this work, I used to have the same surprising result, a smaller file size.

Maybe this is the same case in GhostScript?